# Fix with The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

```
   Text(
    'Owner ${user.data()?['owner']}',
    style: const TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
      fontSize: 15,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
  ),
  Text(
    'Plate No. ${user.data()?['platenumber']}',
    style: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black38,
      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
      fontSize: 10,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: You are trying to access an array value by key `['platenumber']` on a questionmark `?`. Maybe you ment a double `??`?